# How to create a animated intro video in Adobe After-Effects? ( With particular animation, not in general)

Tags: animation, effects, video

**Background**

I want to create a animated Intro video for my YT channel.

**What I need!**

I want the image to show from small size to normal size with constant rotation. Then some images appear with spiral type spin/rotation with size change from small to normal.
Then the those images shift to left side and the channel name appears on right of image with smoke type or crackling type animation.

**Question**

I want the names of animations and effects I should use?

> I searched on internet for each effects and animation explanations but
>   it got tedious and complicated and then I found this stack site. So I
>   am asking here. **I hope it's the right place to ask**.

.

**If anyone can also explain a little bit about how to use them then it would be really helpful too!**

Answer (score 0):

There are not that many options. "In general" (Sorry) you have

- Position
- Rotation
- Scale
- Change the origin point
- Opacity

[image]

So you simply combine them.

---

> Then some images appear with spiral type spin/rotation

Change the origin point so it is not a rotation but a spiral

> size change from small to normal

Scale

> from small size to normal size with constant rotation

Scale + rotation

> Then the those images shift to left side

Position

> the channel name appears on right of image

Opacity

> with smoke type or crackling type animation.

For this, you either create your own smoke or get a clip from an image bank.

Comment: Where's origin point in Adobe AE?

Comment: Anchor point. I posted an image.